# Plotting lists with different sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to produce a plot of four different functions. three of them share the same size but i couldnt plot the fourth one on the same plot because it has smaller size. i am sure there is a way to do it. The time values are from 0 to 10 hours. The first three functions have values every hour (1,2,...,10). But the the last function values are only every two hours (2,4,6,8,10)

Here is what i tried to apply on my data:

```
plt.plot(time, ut_values, label='u(t)')
plt.plot(time, gt_values, label='g(t)')
plt.plot(time, ht_values, label='h(t)')
plt.plot(time, Un_values, label='Un')  
plt.title('Response functions of a linear reservoir')
plt.xlabel('Time (h)')
plt.ylabel('Output rate')
plt.grid(which='both',linestyle='--')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

i was only able to produce the plot without the fourth function (Un), this is the error i had when i added the last function:

```
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (11,) and (6,)
```

Comment: Are you using `matplotlib`?

Comment: It's pretty clear that your `time` array/list is 11 items long, and your `Un_values` array/list is only 6 long. The real question is "how is time being generated and how do you know which values in `Un_values` correspond to the correct time if they differ in length like this?" If you sort that out, seems like the solution should be clear.

Comment: The time is fixed from 0 to 10 hours. The first three functions have values every hour (1,2,...,10). But the Un_values are only every two hours (2,4,6,8,10).

Comment: You can create two variables.Use `time = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` for the first three plots and `time2 = [0,2,4,6,8,10]` for the fourth plot.

Comment: I updated my answer with this new information

Comment: @titusarmah99 thank you it worked that way.

Answer (score 1):

So this error is popping up because matplotlib doesn't know how to map your data points onto your 2D space. It's expecting a 1:1 mapping - for every x value, there is a y value. For every in, there's an out.

```
    x       y
    1   →   0 
    2   →   2
    3   →   4
```

This type of 1:1 mapping is what matplotlib expects when it plots (x,y) points in 2D space. So what does this have to do with our error?

Our error is arising because this is what matplotlib is getting:

```
    x           y
    1   →       0 
    2   →       2
    3   →   ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
```

what are our extra x values being mapped to? Your computer has no idea, hence the error.

In general, if you *know* that your data set describes the system entirely, then the issue is one of interpolation. See SciPy's [interpolation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html) library for some quick options. Or, maybe we just need to provide those extra values to map.

Comment: there is no extra x value, all of the functions have same x values

Comment: Just saw the new comments - It's important to recognize that mpl is *positionally* mapping points together; I.E. two lists of x and y are being plotted as (x[0], y[0]), (x[1], y[1]), etc. so if your case is one where you're wanting to map x[0], x[2] ... x[10] to a list of y[0], y[1] ... y[5], we need to slice x so that the list reflects that mapping protocol that mpl expects, via something like x = x[ : : 2]

Comment: Exactly, i sliced the x values and assigned with Un values and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order for matplotlib to know with which timestamps each of the `Un_values` correspond, both need to have the same length.

If for example all `Un_values` belong to the last timestamps:

```py
plt.plot(time[len(time)-len(Un_values):], Un_values, label='Un')
```

where `[len(time)-len(Un_values):]` means the time slice skipping the first timestamps and running till the end.

And if all `Un_values` would belong to the first timestamps:

```py
plt.plot(time[0:len(Un_values)-len(time)], Un_values, label='Un')
```

where `len(Un_values)-len(time)` should be a negative number telling how much timestamps to omit at the end.

Update after comment:

When all `Un_values` belong to every second timestamp, starting with the first in the list:

```py
plt.plot(time[::2], Un_values, label='Un')
```

Use `time[1::2]` if you would start with the second in the list.